# Manipulating X and Y Properties Unity2D-Javascript

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, coordinates

I'm new to Unity and Javascript, both of which I'm using for my new project, and my question is this: why must it be so difficult to simply access and manipulate x and y values? My whole life I've used AS for Flash and recall better days, when one could simply

```
trace(mc.x);
```

and

```
mc.x++;
```

But from the research I've done it seems that one can't even access a Game Object without typing out a tedious

```
GameObject.Find("mc")
```

And that's just for accessing the Object! As far as finding the object's position or for even moving an object to a point, I have no idea. I tried finding the answer online, but couldn't find anything.

And yes I understand that one can add to an object's position through

```
GameObject.Find("mc").transform.Translate(1,0,0);
```

But even that seems clumsy compared to the AS equivalent of a simple

```
mc.x++;
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: AS3 is a very weakly typed language compared to C#. The code above is correct, however the only "shortcut" could be to create a Transform variable which stores "mc" transform and then do mc.transform.translate etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like maybe you need to learn more about [components.](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Components.html) Any public GameObject field in your script classes (as long as they extend Component, or even better MonoBehaviour) can be filled with a reference to another GameObject by dragging and dropping the object in the Inspector pane. You can then reference the variable like normal.

GameObjects by themselves are not particularly useful, but you can use GetComponent() to find parts you need on those objects -- like Transform, Renderer, Rigidbody, or your own Component classes. You can also create public fields that have the specific Component sub-type you need, and reference them directly.

For example:

```
var anObject : GameObject;
var aTransform : Transform;
function Start(){
    if(anObject != null)
        Debug.Log("I know about an object called " + anObject.name);
    if(aTransform != null)
        Debug.Log("I know about a transform at " + aTransform.position);
}
```

As a side note - GameObject.Find() is really slow! If you use it too much your game will not perform well.

Comment: Thanks, this is very informative. However, one of the main questions I was trying to deal with is how to assign objects coordinate values as I said above. For example something along line of mc.x=10; Any idea how I could do this? I searched quite a while for an answer and thought I was going insane. Other than that you have definitely answered my question Gabriel

Comment: is there something along the line of object.transform.position.x=...? Could you assign values through this property or is it static

Comment: In JavaScript you can just assign values to coordinates directly `transform.position.x += 1;`.In C# you have to construct a Vector3 and assign it to the property like `transform.position = transform.position + new Vector3(1, 0, 0);`